# Change image view with radio button and two activitis

Tags: java, android-studio, radio-button, imageview

I need to help whith my school project.
I have two activitis - main activity whith image view and setting activiti whit two radio button. I want the image on main activity to change when I clicked on radio button on setting activity.
This is my code of setting activity:

```
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private ImageView imageView;
private Integer []photos = {R.drawable.red, R.drawable.blue};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.imageView = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    this.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(id);
            int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            imageView.setImageResource(photos[index]);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can't findViewById in class B within the id in class A

Second thing there are many ways to do that what you want

for example you can use interface

or static variable and this solution is so easy

just create an static variable in main activity and in OnResume function do your logic

somthing like this

```
static Integer photos = R.drawable.red;
```

Whey static??

because you can access it from any where

so just change it from your setting activity

Comment: I'm a beginner, can you please clarify? What's mean "class B and A"? And 2. thing? So I create  static Integer []photos... in MainActivity and in Setting use OnResume whit onCheckedChanged() code, but how can I call it in MainActivity?

Comment: class a and b was just for ex

You want to change the image in MainActivty Right

so you need to write the 
static Integer photos = R.drawable.red; // integer variable not array of integers 

inside MainActivity

Comment: also the onResume function must be in MainActivity 
because you want to chick if the (static Integer photos) changed 

but why OnResume?!?!
to answer this question you have to read about android lifecycle 
chick this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle